# Cloned input names wont show in submit

Tags: jquery

I am having the following:

```
<table>
    <tr class="newZipDeliveryBox hide">
        <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="newd_zipcode[]" value="" placeholder="Fx: 999-2000 eller 2200"></td>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="newd_price[]" value="" placeholder="Pris"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<a class="pointer newZipDelivery">+New</a>
```

With the following JS code, that on "New" it appends a new tr such as the above:

```
$('.newZipDelivery').click(function() {
    if ($('.newZipDeliveryBox').hasClass('hide')) {
        $('.newZipDeliveryBox').removeClass('hide');
    } else {
        var $clone = $('.newZipDeliveryBox').clone();
        $clone.removeClass('newZipDeliveryBox');
        $('#deliveryZipTable > tbody > tr:last').after($clone);
    }
});
```

This works fine, but when I submit the form only the first newd_zipcode[] and newd_price[] values comes. So there is only one item in each element, regardless of how many i cloned and entered values inside?

I dont understand why this would not work? I have read that there could be a problem if the inputs have the same names, but since this is meant to output an array on submit, this shouldnt be a problem?

Comment: Have you tested it on different browsers?

Comment: It doesnt work in Chrome, and my tr last is included in the form indeed

Comment: .serialize() gives me the same as if I submit the form. Only the first  value of each input..

Comment: Have you tested using counters instead of dynamic []?

Something like:

var counter = 0;
...
    } else {
        $('input[name=newd_zipcode]').prop("name", 'newd_zipcode['+counter+']');
        counter++;
        ...
    }

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do

```
<a class="pointer newZipDelivery">+New</a>

<table class="hide">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="text" name="newd_zipcode[]" />
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="text" name="newd_price[]" />
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<form id="my_form"><table>
</table></form>
```

```
$('.newZipDelivery').click(function() {
    clone = $('table.hide tr').clone();
    $('#my_form table').append(clone);
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/YY5tZ/2/)

Comment: now nothing gets submitted. Seems like when DOM is finished loading whatever gets appended wont submit

Comment: Did you check my fiddle ? `#my_form` gets serialized

Answer (score 0):

I created a fiddle for your code and if I am not wrong it's working: 
Check here : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/76/
 Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on('click', '.newZipDelivery', function () {
    var $clone = $('.newZipDeliveryBox').clone();
    $clone.removeClass('newZipDeliveryBox').find('input').val('');
    $('#deliveryZipTable > tbody > tr:last').after($clone);
    return false;
});
$(document).on('click', '.submit', function () {
    $('span').text(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeArray()));
    return false;
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<form action="/" method="get">
<table id="deliveryZipTable" class="hide">
    <tr class="newZipDeliveryBox hide">
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="text" name="newd_zipcode[]" value="" placeholder="Fx: 999-2000 eller 2200" />
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="text" name="newd_price[]" value="" placeholder="Pris" />
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit" />
</form>
```